# Linux Bash Shell read log file compare each line to the reset of the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, while-loop

I have this really large authentication log file. I have paired it down to just the information I need with SED and AWK commands. Now I need to pair up when a user connects and when they disconnect from the server to log how long and what time users were logged on.

In the log when the user logs on you can see their username and IP port. When they logoff all you can see is there IP port. So I need to match up those IP ports and then spit out information from the line where they connected.

#### The log file looks like this:

```
Date,time,Username,Viewer,IPPort <br>
20180911,12:00,Chris,New,55567 <br>
20180911,12:30,Tom,New,55577                  <<<<<-Connections <br>
20180911,12:45,Larry,New,55587 <br>
20180911,14:00,,,55567 <br>
20180911,15:30,,,55577                 <<<<<-When user logs off <br>
20180911,16:45,,,55587 <br>
```

My first thought would be to use a nested while loop. So go to each line, then while on that line go through each line again to find matches. That does go through the file and match things, but it rechecks the top line against itself in the nested loop. There has to be a cleaner way to get this done.

This is what my loop currently looks like.

```
INPUT=firstreport.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read Date Time Username Viewer IP
do
        echo "IP : $IP"
        IPCHECK=$IP
        while read Date Time Username Viewer IP
    do
    if [[ $IPCHECK == $IP ]]; then
    echo "Match : $IP"
    fi


    done < $INPUT
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS`
```

Any suggestions on how I could get this done would be greatly appreciated. My end goal is to have a report I can dump into excel and show a map of user activity.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: Are those ports reasonably unique? If so, sorting by port looks like it would solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, all the port should be unique, can I just use sort in some way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, I've just noticed the port isn't in the same column for both types of logs in your sample (5th for login vs 4th for logout) but your code doesn't seem to try to handle this, is it a mistake in the sample?

Comment: Assuming the port always is in the 5th comma-separated field, the following sort should give you an output where entries with the same port are consecutive : `sort -t, -k 5.1`. Sample run [here](https://ideone.com/C9MOGK)

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake in my sample, it should stay in the 5th column in the whole file. Awesome! I will give that sort a try.

Comment: As you are already using `awk` you could use `awk` arrays with the IPPort as index. Something similar to `awk -F, '$3{names[$5]=$3; logintime[$5]=$2} !$3{print names[$5], logintime[$5], $2}'` [I forked @Aaron's sample](https://ideone.com/YZTDCW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is GNU awk:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    NR == 1 {next}
    $3 != "" { # connection
        conn[$5]["on"] = $3 FS $4 FS $1 FS $2
    }
    $3 == "" {
        if ($5 in conn) {
            conn[$5]["off"] = $1 FS $2
        }
        else {
            print "Error: found a log off with no log on, line " NR
        }
    }
    END {
        print "IPPort","User","Viewer","ON date","ON time","OFF date","OFF time"
        for (id in conn) {
            print id, conn[id]["on"], conn[id]["off"]
        }
    }
' file
```

```
IPPort,User,Viewer,ON date,ON time,OFF date,OFF time
55567,Chris,New,20180911,12:00,20180911,14:00
55577,Tom,New,20180911,12:30,20180911,15:30
55587,Larry,New,20180911,12:45,20180911,16:45
```

---

for older awks (tested with [mawk](/questions/tagged/mawk))

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    NR == 1 {next}
    $3 != "" { ids[$5]; conn[$5,"on"] = $3 FS $4 FS $1 FS $2 }
    $3 == "" {
        if ($5 in ids)
            conn[$5,"off"] = $1 FS $2
        else
            print "Error: found a log off with no log on, line " NR
    }
    END {
        print "IPPort","User","Viewer","ON date","ON time","OFF date","OFF time" 
        for (id in ids)
            print id, conn[id,"on"], conn[id,"off"]
    }
' file
```

Comment: This looks a little more strait forward, would this go in place of my second while loop?

Comment: this would replace the  outer loop and everything in it.

Comment: I have been working with this and can't seem to make it run, it keeps complaining about syntax. It doesn't like the [ ] brackets for some reason.

Comment: Here is the output GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: I just tried it on a server that was running 4.0.2 and it works great! Do you know how I can fix the syntax to work on 3.1.7?

Comment: arrays of arrays were introduced in 4.0 -- can you upgrade?

Comment: I will look into doing an upgrade, but this does work so I am calling this answered. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Given that the logged ports are reasonably unique and that they are always logged in the 5th column as discussed in the comments, you should be able to use the following `sort` command to group your entries by port, regrouping all the informations about an user's connection :

```
sort -t, -k 5,5
```

In this `sort` command we use the `-t,` option to specify that fields are separated by commas, then we use `-k 5,5` to ask `sort` to sort over the 5th field only.

(Note : in the comments I suggested using `-k 5.1` which means to sort from the 5th field's first character, but 1) the `.x` character offset defaults to the first/last character of a field for the starting/ending position and can be ommited and 2) you might have more fields than posted in your extract which would be needlessly used in the sort if the end field wasn't specifed)

Applied to your sample input fixed to make the port the 5th field in logout entries :

```
20180911,12:00,Chris,New,55567
20180911,12:30,Tom,New,55577
20180911,12:45,Larry,New,55587
20180911,14:00,,,55567
20180911,15:30,,,55577
20180911,16:45,,,55587
```

It produces the following output :

```
20180911,12:00,Chris,New,55567
20180911,14:00,,,55567
20180911,12:30,Tom,New,55577
20180911,15:30,,,55577
20180911,12:45,Larry,New,55587
20180911,16:45,,,55587
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/vtArlX).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the inner loop with this:

```
line=0
while read Date Time Username Viewer IP COMMENT
do
  let line=1+$line
  awk -F "$IFS" '
    BEGIN {
      IP="'${IP}'"
      if(!match(IP, "^[0-9]+$")) {exit}
      line='"${line}"'
    }
    NR<line { next }
    NR==line {
      print "CONNECT:",$0
      next
    }
    $5==IP && $4 != "New" {
      print "DISCONNECT:", $0
      exit
    }
    $5==IP {
      print "FOUND RECONNECT BEFORE DISCONNECT"
      exit
    }
  ' $INPUT
done < $INPUT
```

And changing the input a little to look like this:

```
20180911,12:00,Chris,New,55567,
20180911,12:30,Tom,New,55577, <<<<<-Connections 
20180911,12:45,Larry,New,55587, 
20180911,14:00,,55567, 
20180911,15:30,,55577, <<<<<-When user logs off 
20180911,16:45,,55587, 
20180911,16:45,Tom,New,55577, <<<<<-reconnect
20180911,16:45,55577, <<<<<-redisconnect
20180911,16:45,CURLY,New,55577, <<<<<-reconnect
20180911,16:45,MOE,New,55577, <<<<<- foobar
20180911,16:45,55577, <<<<<-redisconnect
```

Gives this:

```
CONNECT: 20180911,12:00,Chris,New,55567,
DISCONNECT: 20180911,14:00,,55567, 
CONNECT: 20180911,12:30,Tom,New,55577, <<<<<-Connections 
DISCONNECT: 20180911,15:30,,55577, <<<<<-When user logs off 
CONNECT: 20180911,12:45,Larry,New,55587, 
DISCONNECT: 20180911,16:45,,55587, 
CONNECT: 20180911,16:45,Tom,New,55577, <<<<<-reconnect
FOUND RECONNECT BEFORE DISCONNECT
CONNECT: 20180911,16:45,CURLY,New,55577, <<<<<-reconnect
FOUND RECONNECT BEFORE DISCONNECT
CONNECT: 20180911,16:45,MOE,New,55577, <<<<<- foobar
```

Which I think is what you are wanting. I suspect on your real data you will need to put in more conditionals to make sure that users and ports make sense.

The slick way would be to do this (the entire script) in python or perl and use a look ahead multi-line regex.

****  Note that the `awk` script is updated but the input/output are still original

Comment: doh. just noticed change in question.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want to do, altering the code now. What is the best way to output the print commands to a file?

Comment: either from the command line: `$ this_script.sh > out.txt` or inside the script, like "`done < $INPUT > $OUTPUT`".

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my syntax. I can't get it to output.

Comment: Did you define "$OUTPUT"?  `OUTPUT="/tmp/file.txt"`

Comment: The code is working just fine, trying to get my input file corrected to use the code.